# postfix concurrency limit with round robin dns

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, cache, email-server, concurrency

Take the following internal round robin dns setup

```
mymta.com. IN A 172.31.1.1
mymta.com. IN A 172.31.1.2
mymta.com. IN A 172.31.1.3
mymta.com. IN A 172.31.1.4
mymta.com. IN A 172.31.1.5
mymta.com. IN A 172.31.1.6
mymta.com. IN A 172.31.1.7
mymta.com. IN A 172.31.1.8
mymta.com. IN A 172.31.1.9
mymta.com. IN A 172.31.1.10
```

Now assume the following postfix setup (assume these are the only tweaks from defaults in debian package)

main.cf:

```
smtp_connection_cache_destinations = mymta.com
smtp_connection_cache_reuse_limit = 750
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 75
```

transport

```
* :[mymta.com]
```

I would expect 75 concurrent connections spread across the 10 A records I've set in DNS.  However I'm seeing more than a few hundred connections to mymta.com and I'm wondering if Postfix is "smart" enough to set up 75 concurrent connections for each IP address.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can I ask why you would want to setup this scenario?  What is the end goal?

Answer (score 1):

You should read this: http://www.postfix.org/TUNING_README.html (Tuning the number of simultaneous deliveries)

and also understanding how resolver work in Linux might help to avoid such "solutions" in the future ;)